# How to realize Brownian motion in real life?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I applied for a quantitative researcher position and one interviewer asked me through phone interview that how to construct Brownian motion.

I said that it can be constructed from random walk by taking limit. However, this method cannot be reproduced in real life.

Then the interviewer proceeded to ask whether I know any real life method to construct Brownian motion and I said I don't know.

> Question: How to construct Browna motion in real life using simulation?

Comment: The path of an individual molecule in a gas can be approximated with Brownian motion. Less seriously but easier to observe: drink a sufficient amount of alcohol and start walking.

Comment: The third paragraph on the [Wikipedia page on Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion) might help.

Comment: I think what interviewer wants is how to generate Brownian motion using simulation.

Comment: Assuming that the Brownian motion $B$ is issued from $0$, we know that $B_t = \int_0^t dB_s$. You can use the Euler approximation to compute this integral, i.e. for $t_i = i\Delta_t$, write $B_{t_i} = B_{t_{i-1}}+ \sqrt{\Delta_t}N(0,1)$. Another to see this is that, $B_t - B_s \sim N(0,t-s)$.